# generating one chatRoomId with two userIds

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

```
    Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> getChatMessages() async {
    return chatRoomsRef
        .doc(getChatRoomIdByUserId(widget.chatter1.id, widget.chatter2.id))
        .collection("messages")
        .orderBy("TimeStamp", descending: true)
        .snapshots();
  }  

 getChatRoomIdByUserId(String a, String b) {
    if (a.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0) > b.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0)) {
      return "$b\-$a";
    } else {
      return "$a\-$b";
    }
  }
```

the problem is I want to create a string named chatRoomId that does not matter if you enter the chat from user id b or user id a ... it should read and write to the same chatRoomId.

but when I tried it creates two chatRoomIds ...

106660068626993723901-110397997856010677626
110397997856010677626-106660068626993723901

Comment: You need an owner key of the room to make unique chat room for both users

Comment: The answer will depend on which Firebase product you're using; if it's Firestore you can use [array-contains](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) and store the two users uid's in the array like uid_0-uid_1 and then uid_1-uid_0.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function ?

```
String getThreadIdFromFriendId(String friendId, String currentUid) {
  List<String> uids = [friendId, currentUid];
  uids.sort((uid1, uid2) => uid1.compareTo(uid2));
  return uids.join("_");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String getChatRoomIdByUserId(String userID, String peerID) {
return userID.hashCode <= peerID.hashCode
    ? userID + '_' + peerID
    : peerID + '_' + userID;
}
```